# How to implement a Custom ConstraintValidatorFactory in order to use @Autowiring in Custom Validators

Tags: java, spring, validation, bootstrapping, hibernate-validator

I was going through the documentation of Hibernate and I came across this article to enable Autowiring in Custom Validators.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-bootstrapping.html#example-using-custom-constraint-validator-factory

But I do not understand the implementation of the getInstance and release methods.

Basically I am not sure what I am supposed to write in them.

Can someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Just for this purpose Spring already has [SpringConstraintValidatorFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/beanvalidation/SpringConstraintValidatorFactory.html)

Answer (score -2):

Look at the documentation for these two methods:

```
public interface ConstraintValidatorFactory {

/**
 * @param key The class of the constraint validator to instantiate.
 *
 * @return A new constraint validator instance of the specified class.
 */
<T extends ConstraintValidator<?,?>> T getInstance(Class<T> key);

/**
 * Signal ConstraintValidatorFactory that the instance is no longer
 * being used by the Bean Validation provider
 *
 * @param instance validator being released
 */
void releaseInstance(ConstraintValidator<?,?> instance);
}
```

It then should be clear that the first one should return a new instance of a `ConstraintValidator` and the other should do whatever is required to do a clean up. It is then up to you how to implement them. This [link](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorFactory%20link) has an example how to implement `getInstance` using `BeanManagerProvider` but you can also have a very simple implementation that uses if statements and then calling something like `new MyConstraintValidator...`. The implementation of `releaseInstance` depends on whether you need to do anything when the instance is no longer used.